# SuperUser question scope

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Most of the questions I see or ask on SuperUser are regarding computer software or hardware, but would other forms of technology that somehow connect to computing be valid questions? For example, would a question about the internal computer of a car be OK? (not that I want to ask such a question :D )

Answer (score 2):

Well, right at the beginning of the [faq](https://superuser.com/faq) it states:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> … and it is **not about videogames or consoles**, then you're in the right place to ask your question!

So it looks like in this, hypothetical, case you're OK.

Actually I think questions about connecting consoles to your home network were mentioned somewhere as being OK, though I can't find the reference at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on this:

- If you are using micro standard computers adapted for the mobile auto market, good question for SU.
- If you are using a computer/laptop to interface with custom/stock car computers for engine management and have questions reguarding software and setup related materials, good question for SU.
- If you are asking about the stock ECU car computer/control unit for engine/car management and troubleshooting, SU might not be the best place for a question in that arena. That would be more of a car forum or community question.

If a question uses a standard computer piece of hardware or software in some way, then it will most likely be ok for SU. Don't be afraid to ask on meta on what is appropriate question material.  Most people will gladly inform you on question guidance.